# Prove that $E_S[e^{2(m-1)\Delta (h)^2}] \leq m$

Tags: probability, inequality, machine-learning

I'm going through the proof for the PAC-Bayesian inequality, present in the book "Understanding Machine Learning (by Shai Ben-David). The author makes the following claim without stating a proof (it's actually an exercise in the book):

Using Hoeffding's inequality that tells us
$$
P_S[\Delta h \geq \epsilon] \leq e^{-2m \epsilon^2}
$$

We obtain that
$$E_S[e^{2(m-1)\Delta (h)^2}] \leq m$$

How does one proves this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\Delta(h)\ge 0$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}_S\!\left[e^{2(m-1)\Delta (h)^2}\right]&=\int_0^{\infty}\mathsf{P}_S\!\left(e^{2(m-1)\Delta (h)^2}>t\right)dt \\
&= 1+\int_1^{\infty}\mathsf{P}_S\!\left(\Delta (h)>\sqrt{\frac{\ln(t)}{2(m-1)}}\right)dt \\
&\le 1+\int_1^{\infty}t^{-\frac{m}{m-1}}\,dt=m.
\end{align}