# Show that $E[e^{(2(m-1)X^2)}] \leq m$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Can someone help me with the following exercise:

Let $X$ be random variable satisfying $P(X \geq \epsilon ) \leq \exp(-2m\epsilon^2)$. Show that $E[e^{(2(m-1)X^2)}] \leq m$. Since $Z = e^{(2(m-1)X^2)}$ is nonnegative I wanted to solve this by using $E[Z] = \int_0^{\infty} P(Z \geq z) dz$.

I started with $P(Z \geq \epsilon) = P(e^{(2(m-1)X^2)} \geq \epsilon) = P(X \geq \sqrt \frac{\log(\epsilon)}{2(m-1)} \;) \leq \exp(-2m\frac{\log(\epsilon)}{2(m-1)}) = \epsilon^{\frac{-m}{m-1}}.$

This implies: $E[Z] \leq \int_0^{\infty} z^{\frac{-m}{m-1}}dz$.

But this integral turns out to be divergent and I have no other idea. I thought about using Markov's inequality but I don't quite know how to apply it in this situation. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: You should try using that for $\epsilon \leq 1$ a better bound for the probability is 1. By doing the computations by head (so I may have made a mistake) I think you will just need to use that $m \geq \dfrac {2m-1}{m} $ for $m $ positive to conclude (I assumed that $m $ is positive, otherwise, your hypothesis doesn't say anything useful.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834585/prove-that-e-se2m-1-delta-h2-leq-m/3834627#3834627

Comment: Wow, I made a mistake when computing the integral. We indeed get $m $, and need to take $m \geq 1$ (treating directly the case $m=1$).

Comment: @d.k.o. Thanks for the link. Didn't see that this question had already been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need $m >1$ for this. Let $Y$ be  a  positive r.v. such that $P(Y \leq y)=1-e^{-2my^{2}}$. The density of $Y$ is given by $f(y)=4my e^{-2my^{2}}, y>0$. Since $P(X\geq y) \leq P(Y\geq y)$ we get $ P( Z \geq y) \leq P(e^{2(m-1)Y^{2}}\geq y)$. Hence,  $EZ \leq Ee^{2(m-1)Y^{2}}$. An easy computetion shows that $Ee^{2(m-1)Y^{2}}=m$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is it possible that you meant $P(X\geq y) \leq P(Y\geq y)$ and $P( Z \geq y) \leq P(e^{2(m-1)Y^{2}}\geq y)$?

Comment: @Thomas Sorry about the typos.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your help.